# Remover linha de arquivo de texto

Tags: python

Gostaria de saber como remover uma linha de um arquivo de texto caso um determinado texto seja encontrado, até o momento consegui ler as linhas e verificar se o texto está presente.

Gostaria que o contéudo ficasse tipo assim:

Conteúdo do txt antes:

```
algum texto aqui
aqui tbm Test
mais texto
Test
```

Conteúdo do txt depois:

```
algum texto aqui
mais texto
```

Conteúdo do código:

```
path = r'Arquivos\texto.txt'
texto_procurado = 'Test'
arquivo_aberto = open(path, 'r')
todas_linhas = arquivo_aberto.readlines()
for linha in todas_linhas:
        if texto_procurado in linha:
            print('Text Found!')
```

Comment: Precisa ser com Python? O `sed` no Linux, BSD, MacOS... Faz isso: Veja a resposta aceita nest [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410757/how-to-delete-from-a-text-file-all-lines-that-contain-a-specific-string). Se for fazer com Python, pode ser com `novas_linhas = [linha for linha in todas_linhas if texto_procurado not in linha]`

Comment: O link indicado acima no box azul  é bem similar. Mas em vez de modificar a linha, basta ignorar as que quer remover - ou seja, é facilmente adaptável pro seu caso

Comment: obrigado pessoal :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ler todo o conteúdo, filtrar as linhas com o termo que não quer e escrever o resultado em um novo arquivo:

```py
path = r'Arquivos\texto.txt'
texto_procurado = 'Test'
arquivo_aberto = open(path, 'r')
todas_linhas = arquivo_aberto.readlines()

texto_filtrado = filter(lambda linha: texto_procurado not in linha, todas_linhas)

novo_arquivo = r'Arquivos\resultado.txt'
with open(novo_arquivo, "w") as output:
    output.write(''.join(list(texto_filtrado)))
```